# Php Tidy : remove link and style tags inside body

Tags: php, html, tidy

I must cleanup some HTML code to remove `<style>` and `<link>` tags inside the `<body>` tag.
I'm already using PHP Tidy to do some cleanup but I did not found how to remove those tags with PHP Tidy.

Do you have a solution ? Or maybe another markup cleaner PHP class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know how to do that with Tidy, but you can use DOM

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;                    // init new DOMDocument
$dom->loadHTML($html);                     // load HTML into it
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);               // create a new XPath
$nodes = $xpath->query('//body/style');    // Find all style elements in body tag
foreach($nodes as $node) {                 // Iterate over found elements
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node); // Remove complete style node
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();                     // output cleaned HTML
```

For the `<link>` elements, adjust the Xpath to `//body/link`.

Comment: Nice one. I hadn't considered that before.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Tidy would be http://htmlpurifier.org/

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant 
>     HTML filter library written in 
>     PHP. HTML Purifier will not only remove all malicious 
>     code (better known as XSS) with a thoroughly audited, 
>     secure yet permissive whitelist,
>     it will also make sure your documents are 
>     standards compliant, something only achievable with a 
>     comprehensive knowledge of W3C's specifications.

---

<sup>*Made this an additional answer, since it is so completely unrelated to the DOM solution.*</sup>

Comment: Indeed, I will have a look at HTML Purifier which seems to be a much more efficient solution.