# Remove section of HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html, screen-scraping

I have an html page that I want to edit. I want to remove a certain section like the following:

```
<ul class="agentDetail">
........
.......
........
</ul>
```

I want to be able to remove the tags and all the content between them. The idea is to edit a page and redisplay it minus some data that I don't want to be seen (hence the removal of some sections).

How can I do this in php?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php Tidy : remove link and style tags inside body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053349/php-tidy-remove-link-and-style-tags-inside-body) - you should be able to solve this issue with slight modification of the DOM solution given there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend parsing the code as XML, then using XPath to de/select the nodes you require. Here's a starting point:

```
$dom = getDom("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
parseDom($dom);

function getDom($url)
{
    $contentUtf8 = $this->fetchDataFromUrl($url);
    $htmlData = mb_convert_encoding($contentUtf8, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");

    $dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $dom->substituteEntities = false;
    $dom->preserveWhitespace = false;
    @$dom->loadHTML($htmlData);

    return $dom;
}

function parseDom($dom)
{
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $nodes = $xpath->query("//ul[@class='agentDetail']");

    // manipulate nodes here...
}
```

Comment: Check out [`libxml_use_internal_errors`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) for an alternative to suppressing the errors `loadHTML` might give

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosting this page directly or are you reading it into php, and echoing it after parsing? In the former case, you can give it a `.php` extension and enclose those lines within `<? if(0): ?>` `<? endif; ?>` blocks

```
<?php if(0): ?>
<ul class="agentDetail">
........
.......
........
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```