# Is there a way to delete all embed, object, script tags in php?

Tags: php, tags, strip

Is it possible to delete all embed, object, script tags in php?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php Tidy : remove link and style tags inside body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053349/php-tidy-remove-link-and-style-tags-inside-body)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just coded this onfly without testing, so please let me know if it doesn't work :)

```
<?php
$output = preg_replace('/<script.+?<\/script>/im', "", $output);
$output = preg_replace('/<embed.+?<\/embed>/im', "", $output);
$output = preg_replace('/<object.+?<\/object>/im', "", $output);
?>
```

Comment: Note that this can't be generalized--these tags can't be nested, but for any tag that COULD be nested, this would fail. CF: /<p.+?<\/p>/ with <p>lala <p></p></p> matches only up to the first </p>

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string

Comment: Please show the OP an example on how to strip just the embed, object and script tags.