# Php: How can we delete anchor tag from inside page list?

Tags: php, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

i want to delete li class and a tag inside the list page in php, i have written the code in  wordpress using `wp_list_pages()` to echo children of a page, but its shows anchor tag inside the list which i don't want.

how can do this?

Code:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-116">
     <a  href="">List One</a>
</li>
```

Expected result:

```
 <li>List One</li>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: have a look at [Remove Link and Style Tags inside Body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053349/php-tidy-remove-link-and-style-tags-inside-body/3053583#3053583) and [Remove all attributes from an HTML tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026096/php-regexp-remove-all-attributes-from-an-html-tag/3026411#3026411) - it's different elements/attributes, but the approach is the same. Just put in the correct element/attribute names.

Comment: What you have is HTML text and once it's rendered into the Client side, you won't be able to delete it using PHP. Perhaps, you could give a bit more detail on what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it client side and do it in php: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php
Otherwise you could use javascript client side and change the innerHtml.